# Recording video from android mobile camera in Unity app

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to solve this issue for a long time... appreciate if anyone can help:)

In my mobile(android) app, I can fetch the camera feed straight to the screen, but saving the feed to mp4 file (to Persistent DataPath or anywhere) looks impossible, anyone ever managed to save to video feed directly to a file?

Till now all I can find is either VideoCapture class that is for windows platform (using UnityEngine.XR.WSA.WebCam) or try to record the screen...(using screen recording plugin in Unity)

By now I think I've searched every google page in the world trying to solve this...
Appreciate any lead or hint:).
Many thanks.

Some Clarifications:
The Video Capture class is the only one appear in Unity Manuel (https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/XR.WSA.WebCam.VideoCapture.html) and it's for windows platform only (Using UnityEngine.VR.WSA.WebCam)...I'm using the WebCamTexture (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6NXkZWXHnc) to fetch live video image to the screen, So I thought maybe it possible to use ReadPixels and save every frame and merge it to video? did anyone try it?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you show the code you are using? Otherwise this would be a pure request for a tool/tutorial/library and thereby off-topic here on StackOverflow. But once I'm here already ... maybe checkout [Native Camera for Android & iOS](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/native-camera-for-android-ios-117802) (free)

Comment: Hi! thanks for the help - the link you added is for open the Native Camera App - it's like open the camera app inside your app - not what I'm looking for, I just seek for a simple record to file (like video capture but for android)

Comment: The first way to write whole thing by yourself, you can create a WebcamTexture to render camera feed then use FFmpeg to save camera stream on disk.


Another solution may be, write native code to launch device camera and let camera do everything for you, after that you can get output image or video path to process that.


The most simplest solution is, you can use any third party plugin like  [Camera Shot](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/camera-shot-19682?aid=1101l34jr) or any other available on store.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Video Capture API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsholographic-videocapture.html) to record videos directly to the file system in the MP4 format.

Comment: Thanks but this API is working only Windows builds and Not on Android (or am I missing something?) have you ever tested it on Android?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I didn't notice you wanted for Android. Nevertheless I know of at least one asset that supports Android API Level 16+, namely [FFmpeg Unity Bind](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/video/ffmpeg-unity-bind-93622). Using it you can record and edit the files.

Comment: From the reviews we get the feeling it won't work on Android 64bit though (another limitation, not to mention the cost which can be a blocker).